# Area between BSS segment and program break (heap end)

Tags: virtual-memory

I was reading somewhere that heap starts right after BSS segment. I tried to verify this with the following code and I get core dump (very likely from illegal memory access):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

extern char etext, edata, end;

int main(int argc, char **arg, char **envp) {
    printf("Size of virtual memory pages %ld\n", sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE));

    printf("BSS segment ends at %p\n", &end);
    printf("Program break (heap) ends at %p\n", sbrk(0));

    printf("Assuming segment above %p and below %p is heap\n", &end, sbrk(0));

    int *heap_ptr = (int *)sbrk(0);
    //Subtract 40 bytes from heap end assuming heap is allocated
    heap_ptr = heap_ptr - 10;
    *heap_ptr = 21548;

    printf("Reading value %d\n", *heap_ptr);

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Output from the execution:

```
Size of virtual memory pages 4096
BSS segment ends at 0x601060
Program break (heap) ends at 0x8da000
Assuming segment above 0x601060 and below 0x8da000 is heap
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Does this mean that there is a 'hole' between end of BSS and beginning of heap? It appears there are no pre-allocated heap pages and they do not begin right after the end of BSS segment.

Answer (score 0):

All this depends on your OS. I am going to assume you're running Linux. Most distros ship with kernel.randomize_va_space=2 which randomizes the heap address.

You can print the list of mapped addresses in your program by adding

```
FILE *fd = fopen("/proc/self/maps", "r");
if (fd) {
    char line[256];
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fd)) {
        printf("%s", line);
    }
    fclose(fd);
}
```

If I run this on my box, I get

```
Size of virtual memory pages 4096
BSS segment ends at 0x601080
Program break (heap) ends at 0x1f37000
Assuming segment above 0x601080 and below 0x1f37000 is heap
00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 00:28 383781510                /home/guillaume/f
00600000-00601000 r--p 00000000 00:28 383781510                /home/guillaume/f
00601000-00602000 rw-p 00001000 00:28 383781510                /home/guillaume/f
01f16000-01f37000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                        [heap]
```

You see there is clearly a gap between the two.

However if I run `sudo sysctl kernel.randomize_va_space=0`, then re-run the program

```
Size of virtual memory pages 4096
BSS segment ends at 0x601080
Program break (heap) ends at 0x623000
Assuming segment above 0x601080 and below 0x623000 is heap
00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 00:28 383781510                 /home/guillaume/f
00600000-00601000 r--p 00000000 00:28 383781510                 /home/guillaume/f
00601000-00602000 rw-p 00001000 00:28 383781510                 /home/guillaume/f
00602000-00623000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                         [heap]
```

In that case, there is no gap and your program does not segfault.

EDIT: as Steve says, this is a security feature. I suggested to disable it to illustrate my point but I certainly do not recommend to leave it disabled for too long

Comment: This is a technique for security, [wikipidia: Address space layout randomization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization)

Answer (score 0):

You have a basic misunderstanding of memory. First of all, there can be multiple BSS segments after an executable is fully loaded. Second, there can be multiple heaps. You are not going to find THE heap after THE BSS segment.